# How to edit excel page breaks using python win32com?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Trying to fit page to print area using python and win32com...
Currently i have only found the solution via VBA macro:

```
Sub PageBreak()  
    With ActiveSheet  
        If .VPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then  
            .VPageBreaks(1).DragOff xlToRight, 1  
        End If  
    End With  
End Sub
```

Can i do it without macro? Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried any python code? If not you should, then post it by extending journalists questions. Otherwise your question is too broad: there is no way of knowing how much you know about win32com and Python etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found:

```
sheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False  
sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
```